# Get the facebook's posts' likes and share posts counts using HTTP request

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get post's likes count using `HTTP` request. I am doing in this way

```
https://graph.facebook.com/10153608167431961?fields=likes.limit(0).summary(true)?access_token=EAANep****
```

and getting the error

> {
>      "error": {
>         "message": "Syntax error \"Expected end of string instead of \"?\".\" at character 14: likes.limit(0)?access_token=EA*****",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 2500,
>         "fbtrace_id": "FgmjqQQgY+J"
>      }
>   }

Is it syntactically something wrong?

Comment: I don't know facebook API but you can't have 2 question marks in an URL. You should try and replace the second '?' with '&'.

Comment: Also your question would be easier to read if you move 'Is it syntactically wrong?' outside of the blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/10153608167431961?fields=likes.limit(0).summary(true)&access_token=xxx
```

You can´t have more than one questionmark, separate the different parameter with `&`.